# SparseMatrix dimensions in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Suppose I create a sparseMatrix in the code below:

```
require(Matrix)    
mat<-sparseMatrix(as.integer(factor(data$V2)),as.integer(factor(data$V1)),x=1)
```

Now, by default, there are no dimension names, only column and row numbers. I know I can specify the dimensions using the 'dim' option but I have 3,000,000 row dimension names and 16,000 column dimensions in my matrix. When I define my dimensions as follows:

```
dn <- list(as.integer(factor(data$V2)),as.integer(factor(
    data$V1)))
mat<-sparseMatrix(as.integer(factor(data$V2)),as.integer(factor(data$V1)),dim = dm,x=1)
```

I get an Out of Memory error. Is there an easy way where I can specify the dimensions?

Comment: I guess you should define `dn<-list(levels(factor(data$V2)),levels(factor(
    data$V1)))` and then use the `dimnames` argument in `sparseMatrix`. The point is that you have to provide just the _unique_ values and not _all_ the values as the dim names (like you are doing).

Comment: @nicola thanks for this note. I will try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: @nicola I am getting an error saying that I reached total allocation of 16274 MB. Does this take a lot of memory when I try to extract the unique values?

Comment: Your matrix can fit in memory, but it isn't leaving enough space to do other operations with it.  Base R is memory-bound, meaning it doesn't use the hard disk for data in the environment.  You need to figure out a different way to work with this data.  Either rent an enormous server with a lot more memory on Amazon, buy a Revolution R Enterprise license and use the RevoScaleR package that comes with it, or check out the "Large Memory and out-of-memory" section of the HPC task view: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html